# Copying text gets jumbled around

Tags: macos, copy-paste, text

I am doing a series of text correction for a game, and recieved the pdf of corrections from the customer. I use preview as a pdf reader.

On windows, I can freely copypaste the content back and forth, but for some reason, when I try on my mac, the sentences gets jumbled around.

As you can see from this screenshot, i copy the text from the right, and paste it in the tool on the left (Smultron) and the lines have changed order.

Does anyone know what might have caused this ? Happends repeatingly, and other

[image: The copying]

Comment: That green text looks like  a different PDF element. Probably that’s why.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem all of the time. The only solution I have found is to try different PDF readers such as Tom has suggested and use [Adobe Reader](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?platform=macintosh&product=10). [PDFPen](http://www.smilesoftware.com/PDFpen/index.html), [Wondershare PDF Editor](http://www.wondershare.com/mac-pdf-editor/), and [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) are other options.